# How to use route path in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I stuck in figuring out how client file find routes function in express. My app structure is like that,

```
|-root
  |--public
     |---files
     |---scripts
     |---css
  |--views
  ...
```

The client side html is as blow, which is in `/public/files`. It can be rendered to `http://localhost:3000/files/like_animal.html` correctly.

```
<html>
<body>
   <form action="/handleForm" method="post">
   name: <input name="usename"><br>
   I like <input name="animal"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The js file is like that,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public')));
console.log('start');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/handleForm', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var animal = req.body.animal;
    console.log(name + " " + animal);
    res.send('Thank you');
});

app.listen(3000,  () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
```

Now I am not sure where I should put this js file in. I tried to put it in `/public/scripts` or `root`, even also in `/public/files`. But nothing works. Every time I submit the form, the browser always show `Cannot POST /handleForm`. As a one-week newbie in express, I am totally lost. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your using `path.join`, but then not using `path.join` to do a join. :)  it's `path.join(__dirname, 'public')`  .. And like @faresoft said you normally don't use `use` for a POST request, app.post would be better.

Comment: I just figure out I should put all router functions under the same file which is used to starting node service. Did I understand this concept correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your script at the `root` then specify the public's path like this.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Another note, `app.use` is used to make a middleware. You should define your route using `app.post`.

```
app.post('/handleForm', (req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Just alter your `path.join`, it's  `path.join(__dirname, 'public')`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I correct the typo, adjust `use` to `post` and move `handleform.js` at the `root`. Still the same error. I already had a `index.js` at the `root`. Do you think there is a conflict?